# What is the direction of pixels in the image stored in numpy array? Left to Right or Top to Bottom?

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am trying to understand image processing in Python.

So, I stored the following 31 x 31 pixel JPG image in a numpy array.

[image]

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

sample = Image.open('datasets/1.jpg')
sample_arr = np.array(sample)
```

Now,

```
sample_arr.shape
```

returns

```
(31, 31, 3)
```

and

```
sample_arr[0].shape
```

returns

```
(31, 3)
```

From this, I understand that sample_arr[0] stores the first 31 pixel values, sample_arr[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CqWb.jpg)] stores the next 31 pixel values and so on till sample_arr[30] which stores the last 31 pixel values. So the total number of pixels we store in the array = 31 x 31 = 961

My question is what is the order of array elements with respect to the image we see? Does sample_arr[0] stores the first 31 pixels from top most left corner of the image towards right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR** the origin is in the top-left corner, first index is the row, second index is the column, third is color channel (R, G, B order).

The numpy array created from the `sample` object contains the pixels in row, column order.

Let's check it on a sample image:

[image: This is a 2×4 binary image (magnified ×25)]

This image has `height=2` and `width=4` and all the pixels are black (`value=0`) except from the top-left corner (which is white `value=255`). It is stored as

```
[[255   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0]]
```

If you introduce RGB colors then every pixel is represented by 3 values, red, green and blue intensity, respectively.

[image]

```
[[[255   0   0]
  [  0 255   0]
  [  0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0]]
 [[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]]
```